# Parsing XML element attribute based on vaule

Tags: php, xml

I have no problem parsing many different kinds of XML feeds and have methods for each different situation. I have come across one I am not familiar with how to attack it.

The feed has element attributes which is not a big deal but some of the attributes of the element are like this where the output is based on a value.

```
tornado="0" funnelcloud="0" wallcloud="0" rotation="0" hail="1" wind="0" flood="0" flashflood="0" other="0"
```

So basically if there is a 1 it will output that data. So how do I parse that so it outputs the listed one? I am thinking I need an array maybe? If so any examples so I can get an idea?

Here is how I parse the data which works great. Lightweight and simple.

```
$data = "http://www.spotternetwork.org/data.php";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($data);

foreach($xml->report as $report){

    $date = $report['stamp'];
    $narrative = $report['narrative'];
    $loc = $report['city1'];
    $tz = $report['tz'];

    $time = strtotime($date.' UTC');
    $dateInLocal = date("D g:i a", $time);
```

-Thanks

Comment: I opened the `http://www.spotternetwork.org/data.php` and see the xml output and you're doing it, then what's the problem?

Comment: That's different data you're seeing. Those are positions reports not storm reports. Storm reports will be at the bottom. Look carefully, you won't see the attributes on there that I posted because there is no storm reports.

Comment: Ok. So you mean that you want to add `store report` like element `<storm tornado="0" funnelcloud="0" wallcloud="0" rotation="0" hail="1" wind="0" flood="0" flashflood="0" other="0"></storm>` in your XML and you want to append it based on value of `@hail` attribute, is that correct?

Comment: I don't want to add it to my XML. I am parsing that from the XML and the attribute returns a value of 1 or 0 depending on what was reported. It doesn't actually return the text value. So I need to convert the return value to the text value. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to specify what you are using to parse the xml but assuming it's simpleXML, you could do something like:

```
$attrs = [];
foreach($report->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    $attrs[$a] = $b;
}

$value = array_search('1', $attrs);
```

Switch:

```
switch ($value) {
    case 'hail':
        echo "hail stuff";
        break;
    case 'tornado':
        echo "tornado stuff";
        break;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know if it was needed or not. I have added it to my original post. So I echo the hail attribute and it returned 1. So I guess I need something like if hail 1 show hail tornado 1 show tornado etc... I not that experienced yet with php yet to figure out the logic for that as that is not something I have seen before.

Comment: I've edited my code slightly. basically yeah, you'll need to have a switch like in my answer.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try. There is no incoming data at the moment for me to test with.

Comment: I am getting a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' on line 62" Do I need to assign any variables in those two lines? Here is a link to the code. http://codepad.org/535iecWU

Comment: uhhh, try doing `$attrs = array();` instead

Comment: Ah that did the trick thanks! Now just have to wait for some data. I knew I should have stored a local copy for testing.

Comment: I am not sure if that works yet as I have no data to test with at the moment. Once I can test it I will.